# Can not Restart, Shutdown, or Logout

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, shutdown, restart, logout

So I have had this problem since installation, first time noticed it when it prompted me to reboot the system, and I clicked yes. Then and every time I attempt to reboot, logout, or shut down - it's always like that; it freezes, forcing me to press-down the power button every time.

Before you answer, no, I do not have cairo dock installed. And it's 14.04 the version we're talking about. I tried to change the grub files and then update the grub but it didn't work. I tried some other workarounds but it didn't work.

And by the way, I noticed a strange thing in the BIOS. when I choose the BBS boot sequence for the HDD, they provide me with three options: Windows Boot Manager, ubuntu, and ubuntu! The last one doesn't work when I put it first. I know that I attempted to install ubuntu 13.10 some time ago, but all that should have been gone by now since I restored factory settings some time afterwards.

Please, any help would be truly appreciated.

EDT :: I forgot to tell that I'm currently dual-booting it with windows 10.

Comment: Your partitions/grub entries have nothing to do with your ability to shutdown/logout/etc. Does it work when you try via command line? Open start, go to terminal and enter this: `sudo reboot -h now` or this `sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: I tried the first one, and it didn't work. The second one however did. By the way. When I try to reboot or shut down while in 'generic' mode in 'advanced boot options', it displays a black screen - and just before it displays some stack-machine looking code, it reports a bug (I think). I'll try it again and give you the exact message ASAP.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to get back to that page to read that, but I can confirm that the problem still persists; still freezes whenever I try to restart.

Comment: From another user on another forum, I got the idea that it may be your graphics driver messing up the process. Going into "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" and choosing one for your graphics card from NVIDIA / ATI itself with the (proprietary, tested) tag next to it, may solve the issue. give that a look.

Comment: Ok I am writing an answer for you now then.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the machine, hold `SHIFT` while it boots to access the grub menu. Select your working ubuntu grub entry and hit `E` for edit. Press `End` to move to the end of the line and add the following to the end of it: `reboot=acpi` Press `Ctr+x` to boot with the modified line. (this will only apply this one time)

**If that >*doesn't work*<, continue reading here, else go to next bold title:**

Since that didn't work, Restart the machine, hold `SHIFT` while it boots to access the grub menu. Select your working ubuntu grub entry and hit `E` for edit. Press `End` to move to the end of the line and add the following to the end of it: `reboot=force` Press `Ctr+x` to boot with the modified line. (this will only apply this one time)

**Permanently add working entry:**

Now that you found what works for you, `reboot=acpi` or `reboot=force`, you can permanently add it to your grub menu. Open /etc/default/grub in your favorite text editor (I use vi at the terminal, so `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`) and look for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`. Simply add your working entry inside the quotes and save the file. Make sure you use sudo to edit it, as the file permissions, by default, only allow root to write to that file.

Finally, you need to update grub from the file you just changed, so do `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

**EXTRA:**

Ought to help you eliminate that extra grub entry you don't need: http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/grub2-revisited/